# Переименование файла в linux

Tags: linux

Добрый день.

Нужна помощь: нужно написать скрипт, который заменял бы русские буквы в название файла, не трогая расширения, на английские (хотя бы 3-4 буквы).

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если в расширении файла нет русских букв, то можно воспользоваться следующим методом:

```
$ echo "привет" | sed 'y/рвт/rvt/'
  пrиvеt
```

Команда `y/` потокового редактора `sed` заменяет буквы первой группы на соответствующие буквы из второй.

Если этого функционала не хватит, всегда есть `tr`.

Comment: Если замена один к одному - тогда tr.
и for i in *; do mv $i `tr Русские Нерусские`; done (команду tr с параметрами надо заключить в обратные апострофы - кто бы ещё сказал, как это в комментариях набрать)

Comment: > кто бы ещё сказал, как это в комментариях набрать

Так же как и в ответе =)
Можно сначала отформатировать в поле ответа, а затем вставить в комментарий.
А, если речь про апострофы, то проэкранировать обратным слешем, вроде бы, достаточно. \`тест\`

Answer (score 6):

В дополнение к первому ответу.

> Если этого функционала не хватит, всегда есть tr.

Нужно учитывать, что `tr` не поддерживает unicode. Поэтому, если имена файлов в UTF-8, то `tr` не подойдет.

> Команда y/ потокового редактора sed заменяет буквы первой группы на соответствующие буквы из второй.

Если же требуется, заменить одну кириллическую букву на две латинских, то можно воспользоваться командой `s`. Несколько команд можно перечислить через `;`

transliterate.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

NEW=`echo "$1" | sed '
  y/абвгдезийклмнопрстуфхцыАБВГДЕЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЫ/abvgdezijklmnoprstufhcyABVGDEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFHCY/; 
  s/ё/yo/g; s/ж/zh/g; s/ч/ch/g; s/ш/sh/g; s/щ/shh/g; s/э/je/g; s/ю/ju/g; s/я/ja/g; 
  s/Ё/YO/g; s/Ж/ZH/g; s/Ч/CH/g; s/Ш/SH/g; s/Щ/SHH/g; s/Э/JE/g; s/Ю/JU/g; s/Я/JA/g; 
  s/[ъьЪЬ]//g'`

mv -v $1 $NEW
```

`$ ./transliterate.sh тест
«тест» -> «test»`

Для пакетного переименования можно воспользоваться командой `find`

```
find . -type f -name '*[а-яА-Я]*' -exec ./transliterate.sh {} \;
```